The staggerChildren exit transition is not working within AnimatePresence - React & Framer Motion
I am unable to get the staggerChildren working on conditionally rendered navigation within AnimatePresence, specially for the exit part. I am stuck on this part since 2-3 weeks now. I have mentioned the sandbox here within which replicates my exact situation. Please can anyone have a look into it, I would be really glad and grateful.
Minimal Reproduction:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/cool-tereshkova-xzdt6y
Steps To Reproduce:
https://s11.gifyu.com/images/SOHwy.gif
import { useState, useEffect, Fragment, React } from "react";
import { UserIcon, BellIcon } from "@heroicons/react/24/outline";
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";
import useScreenSize from "./useScreenSize";

const navigation = {
  main: [
    { name: "Item 1", href: "#" },
    {
      name: "Item 2 - With Children",
      children: [
        { name: "Sub Item 1", href: "#" },
        { name: "Sub Item 2", href: "#" },
        { name: "Sub Item 3", href: "#" },
      ],
    },
    { name: "Item 3", href: "#" },
    { name: "Item 4", href: "#" },
    {
      name: "Item 5 - With Children",
      children: [
        { name: "Sub Item 1", href: "#" },
        { name: "Sub Item 2", href: "#" },
        { name: "Sub Item 3", href: "#" },
        { name: "Sub Item 4", href: "#" },
        { name: "Sub Item 5", href: "#" },
      ],
    },
    { name: "Item 6", href: "#" },
    { name: "Item 7", href: "#" },
  ],
};

export default function App() {
  const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = useState(false);
  const [currentItems, setCurrentItems] = useState(navigation.main);
  const screenSize = useScreenSize();
  const handleNavClick = (item) => {
    if (item.children.length > 0) {
      setCurrentItems(item.children);
    } else {
      console.log(`Navigation item ${item.label} clicked`);
    }
  };
  const handleBackClick = () => {
    setCurrentItems(navigation.main);
  };

  /* Animation Properties */
  const headerVariants = {
    parentElement: {
      isInitial: {
        background: "rgb(47,79,79)",
      },
      isOpen: {
        background: "rgb(211,211,211)",
        transition: {
          background: {
            type: "tween",
            ease: "easeInOut",
            duration: 0.75,
          },
        },
      },
      isClosed: {
        background: "rgb(47,79,79)",
        transition: {
          background: {
            type: "tween",
            ease: "easeInOut",
            duration: 0.75,
            delay: 0.5,
          },
        },
      },
    },
    navigationMenuToggleElement: {
      topBar: {
        isOpen: {
          d: "M 3 16.5 L 17 2.5",
          color: "#143F6D",
          transition: {
            type: "tween",
            ease: "easeInOut",
            duration: 0.75,
          },
        },
        isClosed: {
          d: "M 2 2.5 L 20 2.5",
          color: "#ffffff",
          transition: {
            type: "tween",
            ease: "easeInOut",
            duration: 0.75,
            delay: 0.5,
          },
        },
      },
      middleBar: {
        isOpen: {
          d: "M 2 9.423 L 20 9.423",
          color: "#ffffff",
          opacity: 0,
        },
        isClosed: {
          d: "M 2 9.423 L 20 9.423",
          color: "#ffffff",
          opacity: 1,
          transition: {
            type: "tween",
            ease: "easeInOut",
            duration: 0.75,
            delay: 0.5,
          },
        },
      },
      bottomBar: {
        isOpen: {
          d: "M 3 2.5 L 17 16.346",
          color: "#143F6D",
          transition: {
            type: "tween",
            ease: "easeInOut",
            duration: 0.75,
          },
        },
        isClosed: {
          d: "M 2 16.346 L 20 16.346",
          color: "#ffffff",
          transition: {
            type: "tween",
            ease: "easeInOut",
            duration: 0.75,
            delay: 0.5,
          },
        },
      },
    },
    navigationMenuDisclosureElement: {
      isInitial: { height: 0 },
      isOpen: {
        height:
          screenSize.width < 640
            ? screenSize.height - 112
            : screenSize.height - 128,
        transition: {
          type: "tween",
          ease: "easeInOut",
          duration: 1.25,
        },
      },
      isClosed: {
        height: 0,
        transition: {
          type: "tween",
          ease: "easeInOut",
          duration: 1.25,
        },
      },
    },
    navigationMenuInternalParentElement: {
      // isInitial: {},
      isOpen: {
        transition: {
          staggerChildren: 0.05,
          delayChildren: 1.25,
        },
      },
      isClosed: {
        transition: {
          staggerChildren: 0.05,
          staggerDirection: -1,
        },
      },
    },
    navigationMenuInternalChildElement: {
      isInitial: { opacity: 0, y: 50 },
      isOpen: {
        y: 0,
        opacity: 1,
        transition: {
          y: { stiffness: 1000, velocity: -100 },
        },
      },
      isClosed: {
        y: 50,
        opacity: 0,
        transition: {
          y: { stiffness: 1000 },
        },
      },
    },
  };

  return (
    <motion.header
      layout
      variants={headerVariants.parentElement}
      initial={false}
      animate={isMenuOpen ? "isOpen" : "isClosed"}
      className="fixed inset-x-0 top-0 z-50 bg-gradient-to-br"
    >
      <nav
        aria-label="Global"
        className="mx-auto flex max-w-7xl items-center justify-between p-6 lg:px-8"
      >
        <div className="flex justify-start">
          <button
            type="button"
            className="-m-2.5 inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-md p-2.5 text-white"
          >
            <span className="sr-only">Enquire</span>
            <BellIcon aria-hidden="true" className="h-6 w-6" />
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-1 justify-center ">
          <a href="#" className="-m-1.5 p-1.5 sm:ml-12">
            <span className="sr-only">Logo</span>
            Logo
          </a>
        </div>
        <div className="flex justify-end sm:space-x-3.5">
          <button
            type="button"
            className="hidden sm:-m-2.5 sm:inline-flex sm:items-center sm:justify-center sm:rounded-md sm:p-2.5 sm:text-white"
          >
            <span className="sr-only">Log in</span>
            <UserIcon aria-hidden="true" className="h-6 w-6" />
          </button>
          <button
            as="button"
            className="-m-2.5 inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-md p-2.5"
            onClick={() => setIsMenuOpen(!isMenuOpen)}
          >
            <span className="sr-only">Navigation menu</span>
            <svg
              aria-hidden="true"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              fill="none"
              viewBox="0 -1.5 23 23"
              strokeWidth={1.75}
              stroke="currentColor"
              className="size-5"
            >
              <motion.path
                variants={headerVariants.navigationMenuToggleElement.topBar}
                initial={false}
                strokeLinecap="round"
              />
              <motion.path
                variants={headerVariants.navigationMenuToggleElement.middleBar}
                initial={false}
                strokeLinecap="round"
              />
              <motion.path
                variants={headerVariants.navigationMenuToggleElement.bottomBar}
                initial={false}
                strokeLinecap="round"
              />
            </svg>
          </button>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <AnimatePresence>
        {isMenuOpen && (
          <motion.div
            layout
            key={isMenuOpen}
            variants={headerVariants.navigationMenuDisclosureElement}
            initial="isInitial"
            animate="isOpen"
            exit="isClosed"
          >
            <div className="mx-auto flex max-w-7xl p-6 lg:px-8">
              <div className="py-6">
                <button
                  onClick={() => handleBackClick()}
                  className={
                    currentItems == navigation.main ? "invisible" : "visible"
                  }
                >
                  Back
                </button>
                <AnimatePresence>
                  <motion.ul
                    key={currentItems.length}
                    variants={
                      headerVariants.navigationMenuInternalParentElement
                    }
                    initial="isInitial"
                    animate="isOpen"
                    exit="isClosed"
                  >
                    {currentItems.map((item, i) => (
                      <motion.li
                        variants={
                          headerVariants.navigationMenuInternalChildElement
                        }
                        key={i}
                      >
                        {!item.children ? (
                          <a className="-mx-3 block px-3 py-1 font-tfarrow text-3xl font-medium text-gray-800 hover:text-sky-800 cursor-pointer">
                            {item.name}
                          </a>
                        ) : (
                          <button
                            onClick={() => handleNavClick(item)}
                            className="-mx-3 block px-3 py-1 font-tfarrow text-3xl font-medium text-gray-800 hover:text-sky-800 cursor-pointer"
                          >
                            {item.name}
                          </button>
                        )}
                      </motion.li>
                    ))}
                  </motion.ul>
                </AnimatePresence>
              </div>
            </div>
          </motion.div>
        )}
      </AnimatePresence>
    </motion.header>
  );
}


Can someone please help?
